# Primefaces 5 <p:ajaxExceptionHandler /> java.lang.Exception handling

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When using

`<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="java.lang.Exception" >`

or

`<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="java.lang.Throwable" >`

the primefaces' exceptions handling mecanismm seems not working !!

My question is how can i use primefaces ajaxExceptionHandler to handle all the inhereted exceptions, no matter what exactely it is (`NullPointerException`, `OutOfBoundException`..etc) ?

i just have to mention that the `<p:ajaxExceptionHandler>` works fine when i use it with

`javax.ejb.EJBException`, `java.lang.NullPointerException` or other custom Exceptions.

Comment: I think you should take a look at Omnifaces' FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Answer (score 5):

Remove the type declaration so it's `<p:ajaxExceptionHandler />`

Also Omnifaces is good but, but obviously requires a new jar dependency, if PF now has the ability you may find it works for you. I however, like that Omnifaces is configured in web.xml and you can set it up to handle/cater for ajax and non ajax request with a page redirect.

This is new to PF5 so any issues let them know.

For more info see for usage
[Jsf Ajax Error Handler Usage](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/jsf-2-0-hides-exceptions-ajax/)

Or
[PF5 Exception Handler](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml)

If not defining a type doesn't work, ensure that in your `WEB.XML` has defined the error page for `java.lang.Exception` - if it's not defined there the type definition in your pages won't work.

After reading: [PF5UG](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf)

I'm still not convinced either however - I will do some checks when i get home,.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. After reading the OP's own answer, I almost gave up on finding a generic solution. Fortunately I decided to try your approach, and indeed not defining a type for the `ajaxExceptionHandler` did work. I doubt this is a version-related issue since we're using Primefaces 5.0. Perhaps a deployment failure made the wrong impression on the OP?